# jquery object inside an object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

i am trying not to repeat the selector and get to its children via a the same objects `parentElment` declared variable.

I tried:

```
testimonialsBelt={
    parentElment:$(".testimonialsCntnr ul"),
    childrenElem:this.parentElment.children().length
}
```

I also tried:

```
testimonialsBelt={
    parentElment:$(".testimonialsCntnr ul"),
    childrenElem:$("testimonialsBelt.parentElment").children().length
}
```

but i keep on getting a `undefined` when calling `alert(testimonialsBelt.childrenElem)`.

1. is there anyway to get the jquery object with object literals?
2. What is the rule? when can i use `this` and when must i have the full path?  (in this case `testimonialsBelt.parentElment`).

i am trying to have all these variables in one object called testimonialsBelt. i know i can do this with loose javaScript.
Thanks

Comment: Will the number of `<li>`s inside of `.testimonialsCntnr ul` ever change? This difference is important to determine what sort of solution your problem requires.

Comment: No, it will not change.
Thanks much

Comment: See the edit to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In object literals, you can only use `this` to refer to the object that you're declaring inside of a function.  Try the following:

```
var testimonialsBelt = {
    parentElment: $(".testimonialsCntnr ul"),
    childrenElem: function() {
        return this.parentElment.children().length;
    }
};
```

The difference in calling childrenElem is that instead of using `alert(testimonialsBelt.childrenElem)`, you would instead have `alert(testimonialsBelt.childrenElem())`.

Otherwise, `this` refers to the current scope that you are in (typically window if you are declaring the object literal as a global).

Addressing your edit: I'm not sure what you mean by "loose javascript," but I assume you mean as simple as possible.  In which case, you can try the following, although I'm not a big fan of the method.  It's more verbose, but is easy to understand.

```
var testimonialsBelt = {
    parentElment: $(".testimonialsCntnr ul")
};
testimonialsBelt.childrenElem = parentElment.children().length;
```

This gives you an object where `childrenElem` is static (it doesn't change) and avoids calling `$(".testimonialsCntnr ul")` twice. However, if you expect `$(".testimonialsCntnr ul").children()` to change, then you will need to use my first example.

Comment: This is unnecessarily inefficient. OP would now have to call testimonialsBelt.childrenElem() just to pull the property, which in turn has to call parentElement.children().

This would only be acceptable if the UL is adding list items dynamically throughout the script's lifetime.

Comment: That's incredibly wrong.  It is highly likely that the UL is dynamic.

Comment: How are you determining the UL is "highly likely" to change size after page load?

OP's code snippet is written as if children().length will in fact not change.

Comment: Only a small portion of the code is visible. Without an explanation of intent from the OP, your assumption is illegitimate.

Comment: Perhaps, but the available code certainly does not support a "high probability" of the UL changing at runtime.

Comment: The code doesn't make much of an indication either way. You are correct in that it could be inferred that the values *may* never change, or that whether or not the change *may* be irrelevant to this portion of the code; however, being that the OP is having problems understanding scope and using strange terminology like "loose javascript," it is highly likely that s/he may be taking the wrong approach altogether. Neither of our assumptions are verifiable until the OP makes some sort of a statement one way or the other.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript (not ECMAScript) you can use this:

```
testimonialsBelt={
        parentElment:#1=$(".testimonialsCntnr ul"),
        childrenElem:#1#.children().length
}
```